# how we can Create Primary Keys in a table

Tags: primary-key, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I create a Primary Key in a table. I used the following command to create one, but the key doesn't appear to be enforced:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1,column3);
```

Comment: As a followup to the question, Below is my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, but does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html#supported-constraint-types

Comment: Agreed. Which is to also say no free lunch, so what ever you wanted to have the db do for free in the background, you have to do in the foreground. Which is also great for big stuff, as you don't have hidden costs being paid many times, once you have paid the piper. But the down side is you have to know about the piper, and pay him.. it great, and I love it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the primary key is not enforced in Snowflake, you can use the MERGE statement to insert the data to enforce uniqueness of that key. This approach requires making sure that the source data set does not include duplicates, by using for example QUALIFY function.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    col1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(50),
    col3 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_test primary key (col1, col3) not enforced
);


MERGE INTO TEST AS tgt
USING (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM (
        SELECT 'a' COL1, 'b' COL2, 'a' COL3
            UNION
        SELECT 'a' COL1, 'c' COL2, 'a' COL3
            UNION
        SELECT 'a' COL1, 'd' COL2, 'a' COL3)
    QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by COL1, COL3 order by COL2) = 1
)AS src
ON (tgt.COL1=src.COL1 AND tgt.COL3=src.COL3)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (COL1, COL2, COL3)
VALUES (src.COL1, src.COL2, src.COL3);
```

Only the row a,b,a was inserted.